# Close Websocket connection with a message

Tags: go, websocket

How is it possible to close a websocket connection and pass it a message / code?

The docs only define `func (ws *Conn) Close() error` without any arguments

I would like to receive the event from JavaScript like this:

```
websocket.onclose = function(event) {
  console.log(event);
};
```

I am using [golang.org/x/net/websocket](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/websocket)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Send a [close message](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#FormatCloseMessage) before closing the connection:

```
 cm := websocket.FormatCloseMessage(websocket.CloseNormalClosure, "add your message here")
 if err := c.WriteMessage(websocket.CloseMessage, cm); err != nil {
     // handle error
 }
 c.Close()
```

It is not possible to specify the close message with the golang.org/x/net/websocket package.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/websocket not gorilla

Comment: Oh, that is a shame. Could you add this edit to your message so I could accept it as an answer?